# Can BizTalk Use X509 V1 Public Key?

Tags: certificate, biztalk

We have a trading partner that has supplied a public key ".cer" file for use with AS2 EDI transactions. I've successfully imported the certificate into the certificate store under `Local Computer\Other People` but it doesn't display when I try to use it for an AS2 send port.

The only difference I can see between this certificate and others that work is that their certificate is X509 V1 and the others are V3. Could this possibly be why the certificate is not visible? I can't find anything in the BizTalk documentation that indicates a minimum X509 version.

The partner has used this successfully with other vendors and the certificate cannot easily be reissued. If the version is the problem what are my options?

Answer (score 1):

It appears from [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/eab05af8-6941-4820-954d-f6b0c40a50eb/as2-support-for-v1-certificates?forum=biztalkediandas2) on Microsoft's forums that X509 v1 certificates are not supported by BizTalk. Further information can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa547244.aspx).

The search for a workaround continues. I'll post if options present themselves.